# Can we compute the class number of an algebraic number field without using the Minkowski bound?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

The **class group** of a number field $K$ (or of $O_K$, the ring of integers of $K$) is the quotient group $Cl_K$ (or $Cl_{O_K}$ or $Cl(K)$) given by $Cl_K = $ (fractional ideals of $O_K$)/(principal fractional ideals of $O_K$). The order of the class group is called the **class number** of $K$. The class number of a number field $K$ is always finite.

The class group, then, serves as a measure of the failure of $O_K$ to be a principal ideal domain (and hence, a unique factorization domain, since $O_K$ is a Dedekind domain). For example, $K$ has trivial class group $\iff$ $O_K$ is a unique factorization domain. If one is handed a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ ($d \neq 0,1$ is a square-free integer), one can calculate its ring of integers, and determine its class number from there.

There are plenty of discussions on the network that discuss computing the class number using technology such as the trace, norm, and Minkowski's bound. My question is, is there an example of, say, a quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ out there for which we can explicitly compute fractional ideals and principal fractional ideals of $O_K$ without this technology ? It seems like a long shot, since $O_K$ of an algebraic number field is not a finite ring -- but I have hope, since the class number of a number field is always finite.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has class number $2$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ has class number $1$. Is there a way to see that the principal fractional ideals of $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})}$ make up exactly half of its fractional ideals in a very explicit manner ? Or that any fractional ideal of $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$ must be principal ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for, but there is a thing called Hurwitz constant which can be easily computed from an integral basis of your number field. It is not very hard to show that it is an upper bound for a class number - it is certainly not a very good upper bound comparing to what you get from Minkowski, but you can easily work with it in case of a "small" ring and there is no big machinery behind that. For example, in the case of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ you get a Hurwitz constant cca 10 and then it's not that hard to show that the class number is actually 2. I've seen this computation the other day and it took like two paragraphs.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Always nice to get an extra piece of technology (=